# How are Voyager's 16 thrusters oriented? Table that enumerates them and specifies directions quantitatively

Tags: engines, mission-design, voyager, attitude-determination-and-control

**Question:** How are Voyager's 16 thrusters oriented?

**UPDATE:** Per the 2nd half of my comment below:

> ...Since there was no activity here I decided to add the bounty to get this wrapped up. There are 16 thrusters, what's needed here now **is a breakdown of the thrusters by name and group and the direction that it is oriented (e.g. +x, -x, +y, -y, +z, -z or angles)**

1. Some of the thrusters are angled wrt the spacecraft's cartesian coordinates, by specific angles
2. All of the thrusters can be named, perhaps +Roll, branch 1 or -Yaw, branch 2.

Let's get those all **enumerated, named, and in a table that includes how they are oriented numerically** somehow. Please, not just "Here's a picture and if you are sighted you can kinda see roughly where most of them are pointed in this view, ([I know I can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_consensus_effect))".

**HINT:** From [!Hobbes' answer to *What does it mean when the Voyagers “switch thrusters”?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37341/12102):

- http://www.acme-engineering.nl/reference/BLUEPRINT_VOYAGER.gif (3 MB)

Comment: Do you just need some vector lines added to [How do Voyager's trajectory control thrusters differ from its attitude control thrusters?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23895/195)

Comment: 14 of 16. The purple, green, and orange clusters are paired, and there's one more pair that would be highlighted orange if they were visible, hidden on the back. If you zoom in you can see very short axial guidelines on the drawing. I believe they're all directed parallel to the major axes.

Comment: The roll and pitch thrusters are oriented the same direction, and only the position of them makes the difference in their function, so a table only including the orientation will be of limited usefulness.

Comment: Names like, uh, +yaw, -yaw etc?

Comment: @RussellBorogove sure!

Comment: Something a bit like the Attitude Control Modes
drawing in http://spaceflight101.com/newhorizons/spacecraft-overview/ or at the top of https://mattcbergman.com/2015/07/21/new-horizons-propulsion-system/ but not as fancy

Comment: *looks at photoshop button* ... *looks at vote to close button* ... *looks at photoshop button* ... *looks at vote to close button* ... *shrugs, closes laptop for the night*

Comment: Ha! You are lucky, I've got to stay up to 4AM here to watch InSight coverage.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I've sweetened the pot with a bounty

Comment: <https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23895/how-do-voyager-1s-trajectory-control-thrusters-differ-from-its-attitude-control> might answer your question

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23895/how-do-voyager-1s-trajectory-control-thrusters-differ-from-its-attitude-control might answer this

Comment: @hieverybody the bounty message says "I think there is sufficient information linked here to generate a complete and definitive answer, let's finish this." and the my first sentence in the question and first comment under the question already links to those (you've posted the same link in two comments) so this doesn't add anything. Since there was no activity here I decided to add the bounty to get this wrapped up. There are 16 thrusters, what's needed here now is a breakdown of the thrusters by name and group and the direction that it is oriented (e.g. +x, -x, +y, -y, +z, -z or angles).

Comment: @hieverybody if you think the answer is available there, please consider post it as an answer post!

Comment: here are some vectors [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbfxP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbfxP.png) hope it helps

Comment: Having learned where the other pair of pitch thrusters are, confirmed which set are pitch and which set are yaw, and added a diagram showing the pitch thrusters more clearly [in the other answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23895/how-do-voyager-1s-trajectory-control-thrusters-differ-from-its-attitude-control?noredirect=1&lq=1), I would VTC as duplicate, but apparently you can't VTC while a bounty is open.

Comment: I agree that this should be closed as a duplicate, since it is well answered there.

Comment: @OrganicMarble and yet I still can't name all sixteen of them and list the directions that they are pointing. I don't know the question that I've asked and I don't understand the resistance to making a plain, clear answer available. The information may be in there somewhere, but I don't see it. This is a good-faith question, an earnest attempt to get at some factual information in a form that I can understand. An image **"showing clearly" for example would not answer the question to vision impaired folks** whereas a table can be accessed via screen readers.

Comment: @OrganicMarble in all honesty what I'm feeling here is that smart folks are saying they can figure it out what I want to know from a combination of the picture, intuition, and their background in spaceflight, and If I can't it's just tough luck. I'm sure that's not a correct interpretation, but I don't know any other way to express the dismay I feel about the resistance to making the information plain enough that I can understand it.

Comment: Ah well, it was fun looking at it again.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've updated the question to make it even clearer that a single drawing is insufficient for answering my question about orientations. I'll answer this question within 24 hours if nobody else does it first.

Comment: It's always OK to answer your own question!

Comment: @OrganicMarble yep, but it's sometimes not possible when [in its infinite wisdom the resident question closing cabal invoked *exchangus interuptus*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41791/12102). I'm keeping my fingers crossed and hoping this stays open another 24 hours at least...

Answer (score 1):

here are some vectors

[image]

hop this helped

(background image from [How do Voyager 1's Trajectory Control Thrusters differ from its Attitude Control Thrusters?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23895/how-do-voyager-1s-trajectory-control-thrusters-differ-from-its-attitude-control) and [What does it mean when the Voyagers "switch thrusters"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37340/what-does-it-mean-when-the-voyagers-switch-thrusters/37341#37341))

[image]

Comment: now there is a source

Comment: If you look at the drawing linked in this post, you can see more details about how the thrusters were mounted. That would help you improve this answer, like where you say "this is not clear". It has a nice picture of the pitch thrusters. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37340/what-does-it-mean-when-the-voyagers-switch-thrusters/37341#37341

Comment: thank you it was very helpful

Comment: hello is this active

Comment: Please reread my [comment to you](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32223/how-are-voyagers-16-thrusters-oriented?noredirect=1#comment174785_32223) which says in part "There are 16 thrusters, what's needed here now is a breakdown of the thrusters by name and group and the direction that it is oriented (e.g. +x, -x, +y, -y, +z, -z or angles)" I can't get anything out of this messy picture and to vision impaired folks who use screen readers this answer is useless. There are sixteen thrusters, what's needed is a table indicating the direction each points in spacecraft's coordinate system.